# Is one source to many target cluster replication supported by YugabyteDB’s 2-DC async replication mechanism?

Tags: database, replication, distributed-database, yugabytedb

For the 2-DC feature described here (https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/multi-dc/2dc-deployment/), is one source to multiple target cluster configuration supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a supported scenario. Please join our community slack for realtime support if you run into any issues. Also, if you are trying this feature out, would love to get your feedback/experience.